# How to export webpack modules into global variables

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I am trying to bundle all the dependencies into one file and use it in other js files. This is the code for bundling the dependencies.

```
return gulp.src('./dependencies.js')
    .pipe(webpack({
        output: {
            library: 'home'
        }
    }))
```

`dependencies.js` is just a file with a bunch of requires: e.g

```
require('angular');
require('toastr');
require('...');
```

I've tried playing around with output.library but I wasn't able to access the modules doing `window.toastr` or `window.home.toastr`. `window.home` was just an empty object `{}`.

How would I be able to bundle all the dependencies and access them in my other javascript files as a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

To specify global exports from modules you can use [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)
With it you can export your module as a global var `my`:

```ts
webpack({
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ my: './relative/path/to/your/bundle.js' })
    ]
    ...
})
```

Or you can try your `home` library name instead of the path (probably it would also work)

But I would rather recommend to use [DllPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/) to bundle group of modules into one file and then use original modules names as a references. Webpack will analyze your references and decide when it can use existing bundle instead of doing new chunks. This way you can easily change bundle content in config without changing your code.

Comment: Is this something I would put in `dependencies.js`? How would I go about using `ProvidePlugin`? Do I just put in `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({..})` at the end of the file in `dependencies.js

Comment: @dylanpark I provided an example in my answer.